# EF set foreign key to null on parent delete

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, constraints

I have two models Team and Player

```
    public class Player
    {
            public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class FootballPlayer : Player
    {
        public int? TeamId { get; set; }

        public virtual FootballTeam Team { get; set; }
    }

    public class BasketballPlayer : Player
    {
        public int? TeamId { get; set; }

        public virtual BasketballTeam Team { get; set; }
    }

    public class BasketballTeam : Team
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual List<BasketballPlayer> Players { get; set; }
    }

public class FootballTeam : Team
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual List<FootballPlayer > Players { get; set; }
    }
```

Here's a configuration

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<FootballPlayer>().HasOptional(r => r.Team)
        .WithMany(a => a.Players)
        .HasForeignKey(b => new { b.TeamId })
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<BasketballPlayer>().HasOptional(r => r.Team)
        .WithMany(a => a.Players)
        .HasForeignKey(b => new { b.TeamId })
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

I'm using EF Code First and I want to make that when I delete team, players should not be deleted only TeamId set to null. How this could be done?

Comment: Have you explored using WillCascadeOnDelete(false) while setting up the relationship?

Comment: I works now but the problem when I want to retrieve team it doesn't retrieves Players anymore even if the player belongs to team

Comment: I have added the configuration that I added and worked for me. I can delete, see Null for TeamId in DB. Then I queried the item which has Null, it all works fine. Give it a try.

Comment: See my update. The script should allow you to delete the team and set TeamId to null. I have tested it to work with your entities.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the configuration that I defined for your entity:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Player>().HasOptional(r => r.Team)
            .WithMany(a => a.Players)
            .HasForeignKey(b => new { b.TeamId })
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

**Update**

Above configuration worked for your original entities i.e. simple one-to-many relationship (Team->Players). The new entities involves inheritance which surprisingly remove the effect of above configuration.

With new entities the configuration is still same (HasOptional and CascadeOnDelete), however, it does not allow deleting the team that is in use by any player. It throws

> {"The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   \"FK_dbo.FootballPlayers_dbo.FootballTeams_TeamId\". The conflict
>   occurred in database \"EF6Testing.StudentContext\", table
>   \"dbo.FootballPlayers\", column 'TeamId'.\r\nThe statement has been
>   terminated."}

This is due to the constraint ([FK_dbo.FootballPlayers_dbo.FootballTeams_TeamId]) that EF adds in one to many relationship case. However, what's not clear to me is, the same constraint was added with Team -> Players case and EF conveniently did not "enforce the foreign key constraint".

So why EF does not allow deleting the Team when the entities has inheritance hierarchy???

Ok, let's leave this mystery to EF expert to solve.

The solution (one of the possible solution) to deal with this problem is, you will have to execute a SQL script to drop and create the constraint. This script will set foreign key nullable.

I am interested to find out answer to above question and if there is a better solution in EF (5 or 6 or later version) to deal with this situation.

```
USE [@DatabaseName]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FootballPlayers] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.FootballPlayers_dbo.FootballTeams_TeamId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FootballPlayers]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.FootballPlayers_dbo.FootballTeams_TeamId] FOREIGN KEY([TeamId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[FootballTeams] ([Id]) on delete set null
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FootballPlayers] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.FootballPlayers_dbo.FootballTeams_TeamId]
GO
```

Comment: Now again when I'm trying to delete team which has players I'm getting this exception: "The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.Players_dbo.Teams_TeamId". The conflict occurred in database "SportsStats", table "dbo.Players", column 'TeamId'.
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: @user2412672 - Can you show your configuration, you have to set HasOptional relationship as shown in my answer. Using above configuration I am able to delete the team.

Comment: modelBuilder.Entity<FootballPlayer>().HasOptional(r => r.Team)
            .WithMany(a => a.Players)
            .HasForeignKey(b => new { b.TeamId })
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

Comment: to retrieve the players you should first add using System.Data.Entity; and in the query you do this: var query=db.Teams.Include(p=>p.Players).ToList();

Comment: @user2412672 - Ah the new models would require relationship to be set up accordingly. I suggest you add configuration, context and what code you are using to perform retrieval or deletion as well in OP. Other people would be help to help faster.

Comment: But it seems like configuration should be the same